# File Downloading using Python

Tags: python, download

I have to download file from website after selecting multiple option on the website.

I have three checkboxes each is having same name. I could select one box by using name and value like this.

```
urllib.urlencode({'contentPartnerIds':'67'})
```

I need to select another checkbox in the same group like this.

```
urllib.urlencode({'contentPartnerIds':'67','contentPartnerIds':'68'})
```

but this is not working. Could you please help on this?

Comment: Please specify "is not working".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at mechanize it's great when you need to do things with forms on page and is very simple.

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/